# Android 6.0 not requesting permissions

Tags: java, android

My application asks for permission when I first installed the app, however if I deny the permission and open my app again, it doesn't ask for permission and gets stuck at the

> if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Script_list.this,
>                       Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))

I dont quite understand what does this actually do as the android's documentation says it's supposed to tell users why the permission is requested

Am I supposed to do ActivityCompat.requestPermissions in it too?

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Script_list.this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Script_list.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(Script_list.this, "PERMISSION NOT DETECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Script_list.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(Script_list.this, "USER ALREADY ALLOWED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setListView();
    }
```

Comment: as you have mentioned method `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` is intended if you want to explain to a user why you request specific permission. You can show there a dialog with "ok" button and if user touches  this button call `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`. Alternatively, you can just remove condition  `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` and call `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` straight away

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Let me then move this comment to an answer section if you find it helpful :)